# How to read xml using XPATH in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to read XML data using XPath in java, so for the information I have gathered I am not able to parse xml according to my requirement,

I just want to take the value of bankId

this the example of the xml

I want to read XML data using XPath in java, so for the information I have gathered I am not able to parse xml according to my requirement,

I just want to take the value of 'bankId'

this part of the example of the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:RawData xsi:type="p:RawData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ba="http://service.bni.co.id/bancslink"   xmlns:bo="http://service.bni.co.id/core/bo" xmlns:core="http://service.bni.co.id/core" xmlns:mhp="http://service.bni.co.id/mhp" xmlns:mpnG2="http://service.bni.co.id/mhp/mpn_g2" xmlns:mpnG2_1="http://service.bni.co.id/bancslink/mpn_g2" xmlns:p="http://BP_MultiHostPayment">
  <boList>
  <name>McpRequest</name>
  <bo xsi:type="bo:CommonBillPaymentReq">
  <billerCode>0128</billerCode>
  <regionCode>0001</regionCode>
  <billerName>MPN G2 IDR</billerName>
  <billingNum>820150629548121</billingNum>
  <customerName>EVA RAJAGUKGUK  SH.  M.KN                         </customerName>
  <paymentMethod>2</paymentMethod>
  <accountNum>0373163437</accountNum>
  <trxAmount>50000</trxAmount>
  <naration>820150629548121</naration>
  <invoiceNum>820150629548121</invoiceNum>
  <billInvoiceNum1>INVNUM1</billInvoiceNum1>
  <billAmount1>0</billAmount1>
  <billInvoiceNum2>INVNUM2</billInvoiceNum2>
  <billAmount2>0</billAmount2>
  <billInvoiceNum3>INVNUM3</billInvoiceNum3>
  <billAmount3>0</billAmount3>
  <isDecAmount>false</isDecAmount>
  <trxDecAmount>50000</trxDecAmount>
</bo>
 </boList>
 <boList>
   <name>McpTellerHeader</name>
   <bo xsi:type="core:TellerHeader">
     <tellerId>00004</tellerId>
     <branchCode>0997</branchCode>
     <overrideFlag>I</overrideFlag>
   </bo>
 </boList>
 <boList>
   <name>HostRequest</name>
   <bo xsi:type="mhp:Request">
     <header>
       <hostId>MPN_G2</hostId>
       <channelId>ATM</channelId>
       <branchId></branchId>
       <terminalId></terminalId>
       <locationId></locationId>
       <transDateTime>2015-06-30T22:26:33</transDateTime>
       <transId>20150630T222633N042462J0000001969R840SLEXI0</transId>
      </header>
      <content xsi:type="mpnG2:PaymentReq">
        <bankId>520009000990</bankId>
        <billingInfo1>013</billingInfo1>
        <billingInfo2>03</billingInfo2>
        <billingInfo3>409257</billingInfo3>
        <branchCode>0997</branchCode>
        <channelType>7010</channelType>
        <currency>IDR</currency>
        <gmt>2015-06-30T15:26:33.942</gmt>
        <localDatetime>2015-06-30T22:26:33.943</localDatetime>
        <settlementDate>0701</settlementDate>
        <switcherCode>001</switcherCode>
    <terminalId>S1HKWGA032</terminalId>
    <terminalLocation>0997</terminalLocation>
    <transactionId>013978</transactionId>
    <amount>50000</amount>
    <billerAccountNumber>3010194605</billerAccountNumber>
    <customerName>EVA RAJAGUKGUK  SH.  M.KN                         </customerName>
    <ntb>000000058111</ntb>
    <paymentCode>820150629548121</paymentCode>
      </content>
    </bo>
  </boList>
   </p:RawData>
```

this is my java code

```
try {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Log/contoh.xml"));
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        System.out.println("hup hup");
        String expression = "/p:RawData/boList/boList/boList/bo/content[@xsi:type='mpnG2:PaymentReq']/bankId";
        System.out.println(expression);
        String bankId = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
        System.out.println(bankId);

        System.out.println("hup hup 2");
        expression = "/p:RawData/boList/boList/boList/bo/content[@xsi:type='mpnG2:PaymentReq']/bankId";
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i=0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++){
            System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        }
```

only this that appear when I run the code

hup hup
/p:RawData/boList/boList/boList/bo/content[@xsi:type='mpnG2:PaymentReq']/bankId

hup hup 2

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: So waht happens when you run the code? Could you provide the logs and complete stack trace?

Comment: @Ricardo nothing coming from the node (sysout), I think I made wrong xpath ~

Comment: The example xml is partial or full one bcoz it is not formed well.IT's an invalid xml.The `<boList>` at last line is not closed

Comment: how about trying to debug it, line by line, what happens?

Comment: @Madhan I Just cut it, because the full xml is too long ~

Comment: @Ricardo still not coming anything ~

Comment: Try `//content[@xsi:type='mpnG2:PaymentReq']/bankId` or `//content[@xsi:type='mpnG2:PaymentReq'][1]/bankId` or  `//bankId` or `//bankId[1]`

Comment: @Madhan the `//bankId` and `//bankId[1]` is working beautifully :))

Comment: @splatter_fadli then I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following xpaths

```
 //content[@xsi:type='mpnG2:PaymentReq']/bankId or  

 //content[@xsi:type='mpnG2:PaymentReq'][1]/bankId or

 //bankId or

 //bankId[1]
```

I've tested the xpaths for your xml in this online [Xml Xpath tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Comment: can I ask 1 more question?? how can I get value terminalId, because there is 'terminalId' but is null before ~

Comment: you can go with index `//terminalId[2]`

Comment: I was go to 6 index but still not give me the value that I want ~

Comment: It is inside the `content` right then you can go with `//content[@xsi:type='mpnG2:PaymentReq']/terminalId`

Comment: Try different Xpaths in the link I've updated in the answer

Comment: ok, maybe this is the last question from me to you :p... how to ignore the value that null??

Comment: are you referring `<terminalId></terminalId>` this

Comment: ahhhh, I got it this is will ignore the the null values ~ //terminalId[text()].. many thanks for you, dude :)

Comment: I was gonna say that.Anyhow Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The XPath expression is wrong.

```
/p:RawData/boList/boList/boList/bo/content[@xsi:type='mpnG2:PaymentReq']/bankId
```

would select the element at:

```
<p:RawData>
  <boList>
    <boList>
      <boList>
        <bo>
          <content xsi:type="mpnG2:PaymentReq" />
        </bo>
      </boList>
    </boList>
  </boList>
</RawData>
```

There is no such element in the XML.
You want

```
/p:RawData/boList[3]/bo/content[@xsi:type='mpnG2:PaymentReq']/bankId
```

To select the 3rd boList.

Comment: still not coming anything, that my java code is correct??

Comment: If you would test this with the online XML checker mentioned by Madhan then you would see that it indeed returns "Element='<bankId>520009000990</bankId>'". But your problem has already be solved by Madhan, though the XPath mentioned by him is less performant, and may not be that suitable for large XML's as it may end up selecting too much.